# Can't upload public.pem file for Integrity Api on Google Play Console

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-console, pem, google-play-integrity-api

[image: error message image]

After I followed the instructions to create and upload the public.pem file in `App Integrity Section`/`Change how your responses are encrypted and decrypted` I got the following error message:

`Couldn't upload. Try Again`
It appeared without any other information.

How to solve this?
**Note** that I didn't upload any apk/bundle app to the console just yet because I'm still in the development process.

I expected that the file would be successfully uploaded so I could download the generated file from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed now, thank you again for reporting the issue!

Comment: ty.
I checked and now its fixed.
BUT did you fixed it or you just send a report of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know it is not just you. This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation so it has to be an answer.

I try to upload a pem file and get a 401 both with a new app with no apk and an old app with an apk etc.

POST https://playconsoleapps-pa.clients6.google.com/upload/v1/developers/ Removed to not overshare net::ERR_FAILED 401 (Unauthorized)

This just started happening last week and it was fine before then so there is a good chance it could be something on Google's end.

Comment: thanks for answering, but how i send this error to them ?

Comment: Hey! Thank you for reporting this! For the future you can send us a request via Play Console -> App Integrity -> Settings -> Get support.

Answer (score 0):

When running into this http/401 I noticed I had open privacy declarations for the app in question. When finishing the privacy/government declarations for this application, I could upload the .pem certificate. Hope this helps.